# ckeditor how to add text field dynamically using a button in dialog box

Tags: dialog, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor 4.x . I am creating a widget using dialog box. I am creating a form in dialog with some text input fields. I want to add a button (eg. new field) in dialog box to add new input text field dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this for this purpose:

```
      CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev) {
        var onSelectCb = function(url) {
          var fieldlName;

          if (ev.data.name === 'link') {
            fieldlName = 'url';
          } else if (ev.data.name === 'image') {
            fieldlName = 'txtUrl';
          } else if (ev.data.name === 'flash') {
            fieldlName = 'src';
          }

          CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent().setValueOf('info', fieldlName, url);
        };

        if (['link', 'image', 'flash'].indexOf(ev.data.name) !== -1) {
            ev.data.definition.getContents('info').get('urlOptions').children.push({
            type: 'hbox',
            children: [{
              type: 'button',
              id: 'browseQpSite',
              label: 'Просмотр библиотеки сайта',
              onClick: onBrowseSiteLibrary.call(onSelectCb)
            },
            {
              type: 'button',
              id: 'browseQpContent',
              label: 'Просмотр библиотеки контента',
              onClick: onBrowseContentLibrary.call(onSelectCb)
            }]
          });
        }
      });

      CKEDITOR.replace(self._editorElem.id, getCkEditorConfig(self));
    }
```

This code add two buttons with custom onClick handlers